# How to extend row-level security to views in Postgres RDS without using 'security_invoker' option?

Tags: postgresql, view, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a view with "security_invoker" set to TRUE to check the user's access privilege and implement the row-level security set on the underlying table(s).

This is working fine in an environment with local installation of PostgreSQL.

Executing the same script to create the view in Postgres RDS database is throwing an error: ERROR:  22023 | unrecognized parameter "security_invoker"

What could be an alternative in RDS to implement the same and make sure the row-level security set in the tables is extended to the views?

The following is how I defined my view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW [view name] 
  WITH (security_invoker = TRUE) AS 
SELECT columns FROM tablename;
```

Currently trying to find an alternative of "security_invoker" as view option that would work in a RDS database.